# I change background color of button with jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I change background color of a button using the jQuery `click` function, but I want to do this without jQuery. How can I use it only with CSS? Here are my codes and jsfiddle demo below.

```
.colorButton{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="colorButton">Click me</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.colorButton').click(function (){
            $(this).css("background","yellow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myyhs84b/

Comment: Click & change events are the area of Javascript. There is no equivalent in CSS.

Comment: this is such a simple and duplicate question that you confused most of us that you needed something completely different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using checkbox/radio  CSS hack, this could be a solution: {please don't, handling click should be done in javascript anyway}

***HTML:***

```
<div class="buttons">
    <input id="rd_btn" type="radio" />
    <button class="colorButton">
        <label for="rd_btn">Click me</label>
    </button>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.colorButton {
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.colorButton {
    padding: 0;
}
.colorButton label {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
}
#rd_btn {
    display: none;
}
#rd_btn:checked + button {
    background: yellow;
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 2):

```css
.colorButton{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
 }
.colorButton:focus{
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="colorButton">Click me</button>
```

[EDIT] okay, now pure CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS:

```
.colorButton:active, 
.colorButton:focus{
    background:yellow;
}
```

But on outside click it remain the same. Because you have to add a new class or have to implement the existing code that apply the inline style to your DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

The `:focus` pseudo class in CSS is used for styling an element that is currently targeted by the keyboard, or activated by the mouse.

**CSS**

```
.colorButton{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.colorButton:focus{
    background: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="colorButton">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vf40acbx/)

**FYI**

[focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no click event in HTML and CSS, you can use functionality of pseudo class :checked to change something.
Just style the label as some button, than bind some click functionality in jquery.

Take a look at this exaples:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-flat-checkboxes

Or :active pseudo class. Example here:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-a-css-3d-push-button

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this only with CSS as there isn't anything like a "clicked" property.

Maybe :active or :hover will fit your needs.

```
.colorButton1:active
{
    background: green;
}

.colorButton2:hover
{
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbjsnp42/

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you could do is using :active or :focus but the first will only should work while you are pressing the button while the second will only work unless you don't press anywhere else

what you can do is defining a class in your CSS and then via JS add the class on click